# Add custom action of installing msi before the setup in installer project

Tags: c#, installation, windows, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am creating an installer project for one of my windows applications .

I want to make sure that an msi is installed first i.e. before the primary output is installed . The msi in question here is `Microsoft VisualFoxPro OLEDB` .

So if I tried adding custom action as [image]

So if I change the file type to all files and try adding the msi , it gives an error saying

> Not a valid file type for custom action

Is there any other way to do what I am trying to achieve here?

Comment: You must not add the msi directly. if the MSI is a dependency (like VC++ runtime) try adding it to the bootstrapper instead. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Visual Studio custom actions run after all the files have been installed, so you cannot use a custom action to install another MSI before your primary output is installed. Also, running an MSI-based install from a custom action is likely to fail because concurrent MSI-based installs are not allowed.

The normal way to do this is to create a bootstrapper package that installs dependencies before your MSI is installed, start here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

Comment: `The normal way to do this is` so what is the abnormal way here?

Comment: It's abnormal to try to run a custom action to install an MSI-based product install from a VS custom action because it doesn't work, as both I and Digvijay (in his comment) say. That's one of the main reasons for the idea of a prerequisites installer. Anything that installing as a prerequisite is unusual and often not possible.

Comment: A quick action. How do I associate the package.xml to my application

Answer (score 0):

I found an associated article that i have used previously to package a dependency (which i did not want in the pre-requisites) [on codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33883/Invoke-another-MSI-from-an-MSI)