# VSTO installer and Deployment Manifest file

Tags: visual-studio, office-addins

I am trying to make an installer for a PowerPoint Addin using Visual Studio Installer.

The installer installs each required files but does not execute the VSTO Deployment Manifest, and then my add-in is not included in PowerPoint.
I went to Custom Actions menu and wants to add the action of executing VSTO Deployment Manifest file but I have the following error: **not a valid file type for a custom action** (it seems to expect .exe .dll .vbs or .js files).

I have searched similar questions and found [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588445/add-custom-action-of-installing-msi-before-the-setup-in-installer-project/43617163) but even if the error message is the same, I think the problem is different.

Do you know how to solve it and execute the VSTO Deployment Manifest file?

Comment: The deployment manifest is meant for ClickOnce deployment.  Which is the opposite of Visual Studio Installer deployment.  It is not obvious which method you might prefer, but if you use VSI then you have to [register the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3087063/17034).

Comment: I don't want to use ClickOnce. I didn't know that the deployment manifest was intended for this kind of installation